# Highlight cells which are different, by comparing 2 excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a updated version of a excel sheet (no rows have been added or deleted, only some cells in each row have been changed), I want to compare it with the original sheet and highlight the cells which have changed. I found [this solution](http://www.ehow.com/facts_6905320_compare-excel-spreadsheets-highlight-missing.html), however it marks the changed cells in a third sheet but whereas I want to highlight the changed cells in the updated sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro would probably be best but I'm assuming your requirement is 'once off' and this can be achieved without a macro, which might be simpler. Copy your original sheet's contents into the updated one and use conditional formatting, as in example:

[image: SU489661 example]